# loop rereading first file for given length

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I'm trying to write a loop that checks how much overlap there is in different date ranges. There are two groups with multiple files files where I want to see the most overlap. My issue at the moment is that when I run the loops for `indoor_data` and `outdoor_data` information for one of the entries appears to be written for every length.

I currently have this:

```
library(DescTools)
library(dplyr)
library(readr)
```

```
indoor <- list.files("indoor", full.names = TRUE)
outdoor <- list.files("outdoor", full.names = TRUE)
indoor
outdoor
```

```
indoor_data <- for(i in 1:length(indoor)){
  assign(paste0("data", i),
         read_csv(paste0("",
                         indoor[1])))
}

outdoor_data <- for(i in 1:length(outdoor)){
  assign(paste0("data", i),
         read_csv(paste0("",
                         outdoor[1])))
}
```

I was originally thinking it had something to do with the paste0, but I don't think that would make sense. The `list.files` for indoor and outdoor read from folders then I have copies of those files with the same name in my directory. Maybe it could be that, but the files have the same names and data so idk.

Comment: do not `assign` but rather maintain everything in a list

Comment: or if you want to write everything onto global environment, you should distinguish them eg `paste0("data_outdoor", i)` vs paste0("data_indoor", i)`

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are always reading the same file; e.g., outdoor[1].  Shouldn't that be outdoor[i] in your loop?